# how to split string in sql server having two different delimiter

Tags: sql-server

I want to pass string to store procedure like
'1:3,2:4,5:8' where 1,2,5 are product ids and 3,4,8 are respective quantities.
It should be added to table like following

```
PID|Qty
1  |3
2  |4
5  |8
```

I have created splitting function

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO
```

---

Comment: Have you considered using [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx) ?

Comment: If you are going to stick with using a splitter you really need to throw the one you posted away. Take a look at the answer from SqlZim, there are several splitters listed there that will blow the doors off this multi-statement table valued function with loops.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you could split your string how you describe, using a CSV Splitter function by Jeff Moden:

```
declare @str varchar(100) = '1:3,2:4,5:8' ;

select 
    s.ItemNumber
  , Product  = left(s.Item,charindex(':',s.Item)-1)
  , Quantity = stuff(s.Item,1,charindex(':',s.Item),'')
from (select * from [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K] (@str,',')) as s
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/HWSVW98120

returns:

```
+------------+---------+----------+
| ItemNumber | Product | Quantity |
+------------+---------+----------+
|          1 |       1 |        3 |
|          2 |       2 |        4 |
|          3 |       5 |        8 |
+------------+---------+----------+
```

Splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

---

You should really consider using Table Valued Parameters instead.

- [User-Defined Table Types](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Table-Valued Parameters - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 Table-Valued Parameters and C# Custom Iterators: A Match Made In Heaven! - Leonard Lobel](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/)
- [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)
- [Maximizing Performance with Table-Valued Parameters - Dan Guzman](http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/)
- [Maximizing throughput with tvp - sqlcat](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2013/09/23/maximizing-throughput-with-tvp/)
- [How to use TVPs with Entity Framework 4.1 and CodeFirst](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179481/Code-First-Stored-Procedures)

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Many great set based splitters in the articles referenced and followed up with a whole list of articles explaining why a table valued parameter is far superior. I would give you more +1s on this if I could.

Comment: I have to agree with Sean.  Truly a VALUE-ADDED Answer  +1